# How to convert JavaScript date object to ticks

Tags: c#, javascript

How should I convert JavaScript date object to ticks? I want to use the ticks to get the exact date for my C# application after synchronization of data.

Comment: Bear in mind that the date/time of the browser may be set to any time-zone so your data will not be relative to UTC on the server. I normally compensate by injecting the server's `utcnow` in ticks (relative to 1970) into the page and storing the difference between that value and `+new Date()` at page start. Then all date/time can be offset by that amount. Any error is then just down to the page latency.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

If you want to convert your `DateTime` object into universal ticks then use the following code snippet:

```
var ticks = ((yourDateObject.getTime() * 10000) + 621355968000000000);
```

> There are 10000 ticks in a millisecond. And 621.355.968.000.000.000 ticks between 1<sup>st</sup> Jan 0001 and 1<sup>st</sup> Jan 1970.

Comment: This gets the ticks when you are in C#.  See pointy's answer below for a javascript way.

Comment: the added number doesn't work with me it always give me time:21:00 in previous day , but this one (621356076000000000) is worked fine, any Idea??

Comment: in Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) the correct value is (621356076000000000), so what the difference between these two values?

Comment: What programming language is your answer for - c# or JavaScript?  I.e., where is this implemented?

Comment: @muniR I think it's because you mixed UTC and local time. 621355968000000000 is UTC. Your number 621356076000000000 would be so its works with your local time (you are 3 hours behind UTC time in your timezone)

Answer (score 64):

The JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) type's origin is the Unix epoch: midnight on 1 January 1970.

The .NET [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx) type's origin is midnight on 1 January 0001.

You can translate a JavaScript `Date` object to .NET ticks as follows:

```
var yourDate = new Date();  // for example

// the number of .net ticks at the unix epoch
var epochTicks = 621355968000000000;

// there are 10000 .net ticks per millisecond
var ticksPerMillisecond = 10000;

// calculate the total number of .net ticks for your date
var yourTicks = epochTicks + (yourDate.getTime() * ticksPerMillisecond);
```

Comment: `(621355968e9 + (new Date()).getTime() * 1e4)` condenses these 4 lines down once you have the understanding. Great share @LukeH

Answer (score 39):

If by "ticks" you mean something like "milliseconds since the epoch", you can call ".getTime()".

```
var ticks = someDate.getTime();
```

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), the returned value is an

> Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch).

Comment: ticks != milliseconds , so in C# A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds

Answer (score 15):

Expanding on the accepted answer as why `635646076777520000` is added.

Javascript `new Date().getTime() or Date.now()` will return number of milliseconds passed from `midnight of January 1, 1970`.

In .NET([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) under `Remarks` sections)

> The DateTime value type represents dates and times with values ranging from 00:00:00 (midnight), January 1, 0001 Anno Domini (Common Era) through 11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D. (C.E.) in the Gregorian calendar.

`621355968000000000` is the value of ticks from `midnight Jan 1 01 CE` to `midnight Jan 1 1970`

So, in .NET

```
  Console.Write(new DateTime(621355968000000000))
  // output 1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM
```

Hence to convert javascript time to .Net ticks

```
 var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

 // 10,000 ticks in 1 millisecond
 // jsTicks is number of ticks from midnight Jan 1, 1970
 var jsTicks = currentTime * 10000;

 // add 621355968000000000 to jsTicks
 // netTicks is number of ticks from midnight Jan 1, 01 CE
 var netTicks = jsTicks + 621355968000000000;
```

Now, in .NET

```
 Console.Write(new DateTime(netTicks))
 // output current time
```

Answer (score 10):

Date in JavaScript also contains offset. If you need to get rid of it use following:

```
return ((date.getTime() * 10000) + 621355968000000000) - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 600000000);
```

I use Skeikh's solution and subtract ticks for 'offset'.

Answer (score 3):

That should be `date.GetTime()`. Be aware that C# and Javascript using different initial dates so use something like this to convert to C# DateTime.

```
public static DateTime GetDateTime(long jsSeconds)
{
    DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return unixEpoch.AddSeconds(jsSeconds);
}
```

Comment: I think date.GetTime() is in milliseconds