# JSON WCF Service with System.DateTime parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, wcf, date

I have created the following JSON WCF Service that accepts a .NET `System.DateTime` value as an input parameter:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
ReclaimedH2OMetric GetCurrentReclaimedH2OMetric(System.DateTime currentDate);
```

When I try to consume the service using `jQuery` in my web page I get the following error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request.  The exception
>   message is 'SqlDateTime overflow.  Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00
>   AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.'

Here is my jQuery code:

```
var rawResults;
var currentDate = new Date('10/1/2012');
var jsonDate = '\\/Date(' + currentDate.getTime() + ')\\/';

$.ajax(
{
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://www.mydomain.com/Dashboard_WaterResources/WCFService/Dashboard.svc/GetCurrentReclaimedH2OMetric",
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{"currentDate": "' + jsonDate + '"}',
    success: function (results) {
        rawResults = results;
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

The following line of code `var jsonDate = '\\/Date(' + currentDate.getTime() + ')\\/';` was trying to format the date in the proper JSON format using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date) question as a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the WCF service signature to accept a `long` data type instead of the `System.DateTime` object.

Also, I was having issues with how I was formatting the `data` property of the `ajax` jQuery call.  Here is the updated code that worked:

```
var rawResults;
var currentDate = new Date('10/1/2012 12:00 AM');
var jsonDate = ConvertDateToTicks(currentDate);

$.ajax(
{
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://localhost/Dashboard_WaterResources/WCFService/Dashboard.svc/GetCurrentReclaimedH2OMetric",
    data: { dateInTicks: jsonDate },
    success: function (results) {
        rawResults = results;
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The integer inside the jsonDate should be the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

[How to convert JavaScript date object to ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966559/how-to-convert-javascript-date-object-into-ticks)

Or consider using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-offset/) to get the milliseconds.

Comment: I tried the converting the `jsonDate` variable into ticks using the formula provided in the link and still got the same sql overflow error.

Comment: if you put a breakpoint on the server in the WCF service, what does it say for the date?

Comment: currentDate = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}

Comment: That's DateTime.MinValue, which means the WCF service isn't recognizing the date you're passing in. What happens if you remove the double backslashes, so it's like '\/Date(...)\/'?

Comment: I changed the signature of the WCF service to accept a `long` data type instead of `System.DateTime` and it was zero when passed to the service.  It look like the input parameter is not recognized during my jQuery ajax call.

Comment: I think it's the double backslashes, they don't need to be escaped. This is a good article as well: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx