# Conversion of date into long format, How it works?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to convert date object into long format (may be in milliseconds format) as we do in java.
So to fulfill my need, after some trial and error, I found below way which works for me:

```
var date = new Date();  
var longFormat = date*1;  // dont know what it does internally
console.log(longFormat); // output was 1380625095292
```

To verify, I reverse it using `new Date(longFormat);` and it gave me correct output. In short I was able to fulfill my need some how, but I am still blank what multiplication does internally ? When I tried to multiply current date with digit 2, it gave me some date of year 2057 !! does anyone know, what exactly happening ?

Comment: Please read the manual ... this is the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 (equivalent to `date.getTime()`)

Comment: @devnull69 could you please share some resource link which can clarify my doubts?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime might be a good start

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The long format displays [**the number of ticks**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) after **01.01.1970**, so for now its about 43 years.

`*` operator forces argument to be cast to number, I suppose, `Date` object has such casting probably with `getTime()`.

You double the number of milliseconds - you get 43 more years, hence the 2057 (or so) year.

Answer (score 5):

What you are getting when you multiply, is ticks

Visit: **[How to convert JavaScript date object into ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966559/how-to-convert-javascript-date-object-into-ticks)**

Also, when you `* 2` it, you get the double value of ticks, so the date is of future

```
var date = new Date()
var ticks = date.getTime()
```

**[ref: Javascript Date Ticks](http://forums.asp.net/t/936173.aspx)**

`getTime` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970. So when you `* 1` it, you might have got value of this milliseconds. When you `* 2` it, those milliseconds are doubled, and you get date of 2057!!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript date objects are based on a UTC [time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) that is milliseconds since 1 January 1970. It just so happens that Java uses the same epoch but the time value is seconds.

To get the time value, the *getTime* method can be used, or a mathematic operation can be applied to the date object, e.g.

```
var d = new Date();
alert(d.getTime());  // shows time value
alert(+d);           // shows time value
```

The Date constructor also accepts a time value as an argument to create a date object, so to copy a date object you can do:

```
var d2 = new Date(+d);
```

If you do:

```
var d3 = new Date(2 * d);
```

you are effectively creating a date that is (very roughly):

```
1970 + (2013 - 1970) * 2 = 2056
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates are internally stored as a timestamp, which is a long-object ([more info on timestamps](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)). This is why you can create Dates with new Date(long). If you try to multiply a Date with an integer, this is what happens:

```
    var date = new Date();
    var longFormat = date*1;
    // date*1 => date.getTime() * 1

    console.log(longFormat); // output is 1380.....
```

Javascript tries to find the easiest conversion from date to a format that can be multiplied with the factor 1, which is in this case the internal long format

Answer (score 0):

Just use a date object methods.

Read the docs: [JavaScript Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

```
var miliseconds=yourDateObject.getMiliseconds();
```

If You want to get ticks:

```
var ticks = ((yourDateObject.getTime() * 10000) + 621355968000000000);
```

or

```
var ticks = someDate.getTime();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try the [parsing functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) of the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), whose result you then can [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString):

>

```
 new Date("04/06/13").toString()
"Sun Apr 06 1913 00:00:00 GMT+0200"
```

// or something
But the parsing is implementation-dependent, and there won't be many engines that interpret your odd DD/MM/YY format correctly. If you had used MM/DD/YYYY, it probably would be recognized everywhere.

Instead, you want to ensure how it is parsed, so have to do it yourself and feed the single parts into the constructor:

```
var parts = "04/06/13".split("/"),
    date = new Date(+parts[2]+2000, parts[1]-1, +parts[0]);
console.log(date.toString()); // Tue Jun 04 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

Comment: why is this downvoted? Worked for me... Just pass the "ticks" into `new Date(ticks).toString();`