# Sending a paramater to postman api get request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-get, postman

I have a controller to get a count of items that are greater then a certain date. The repository appears as:

```
    public Dictionary<int, int> GetAllComplaintsCount(DateTime start)
    {
        try
        {
            return _context.Checklists
                .Where(a => a.COMPLAINT.Received_DT > start)
                .GroupBy(a => a.MonitorEnteredEmpID)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Could not get am with checklist", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Edit** I've included my routers to see if it is correct:

```
         app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "crams/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "route",
                template: "crams/{controller}/{action}/{start?}");
        });
```

**Question** Without the start parameter, I am able to get http://localhost:8000/crams/api/counts through postman. I am unsure though, how to incorporate the date through postman so it can only pull dates that are greater than start.

I've tried

> http://localhost:8000/crams/api/counts/2016-1-1
>   but it comes back null.

Comment: Pass the date as a string and parse it within the action.

Comment: @Jasen that's what the default model binder does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /api/counts/2016-1-1 comes back as null

Your API is:

```
... GetAllComplaintsCount(DateTime start)
```

so your url should be:

```
/api/counts?start=2016-1-1
```

This would be with the default routing.  As you've not included routing in your question, I assume (given the symptoms) that it's the default:

```
/api/{controller}/{id}
```

ie using `/api/counts/2016-1-1` specifies "2016-1-1" as the `id` parameter, but you don't have an `id` parameter and you've not specified a value for `start`, so you get null.

You can add a route as

```
/api/{controller}/{start}
```

---

I've just created an api as:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string Test(DateTime d)
    {
        return d.ToString();
    }
```

and called, via postman (though any client would give the same result)

http://localhost/api/../Test?d=2016-1-1

and it returned the expected "01/01/2016 00:00:00"

Comment: I appreciate your thoughtful answer! I have attempted to add a route under my default route and named it route, and now my routes look like this:            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "crams/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "route",
                    template: "crams/{controller}/{action}/{start?}");
            });

Comment: Then I used your test to see if it would work: so I added the test httpget, but when I run "http://localhost:8000/crams/api/counts/Test?d=2016-1-1" I get 404 not found! Can you tell me if I am making a mistake anywhere?

Comment: First - did your original work with `../counts?start=2016-1-1` ?

Comment: No, nothing has worked with adding a parameter. I am getting a null still.

Comment: Next, it looks like you've changed the MVC routes, not the API ones and the 'default' one should always be last as it will hit them in order.

Comment: Try simplifying the existing method to just return `start.ToString()` before adding new ones / routes.  Get the parameter working with `?start=...` before making it "nicer".   Put a breakpoint inside the method and see what the value is.  Could be that you don't have any records - so eliminate the DB part and stick with simple .ToString

Comment: I got it :) You rock.

Comment: One more questions,  if I wanted an end date would I just add another ? as http://localhost:8000/crams/api/counts?startdate=2014-1-1?enddate=2016-1-1

Comment: Well, you'd use `&` for additional query string parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass ticks to your API

http://localhost:8000/crams/api/counts/636027305821590000

And then

```
public Dictionary<int, int> GetAllComplaintsCount(Int64 dateTicks)
    {
        try
        {
            var startDate = new DateTime(dateTicks);
            return _context.Checklists
                .Where(a => a.COMPLAINT.Received_DT > startDate)
                .GroupBy(a => a.MonitorEnteredEmpID)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Could not get am with checklist", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is an info on how to get Ticks from a Date (using JS)

[How to convert JavaScript date object to ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966559/how-to-convert-javascript-date-object-to-ticks)

Hope this helps:

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a .net env to test with for now... do you get errors? I've send DateTime params before to applications using either ticks or a specific format string and used .ParseExact... If there is an error on my code example I can update it

Comment: The issue was that the routing didn't match the parameter name - which would also be the case here.