# Javascript date stored in a C# string to C# Datetime

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

how can I convert "/Date(1479250800000)/" String to a C# Datetime?

Thanks in advance

Comment: that's not a javascript date string it came from your back end code in the first place

Comment: is this jsonresult

Comment: I know, but I need to store it in a string because this field can contain any type of data. In JS I would create the date using moment("/Date(1479250800000)/") but I don't know how to get the same result in C#. Big thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the value inside the brackets is number of ticks:

```
var datstr = "/Date(1479250800000)/";
long ticks = Convert.ToInt64(datstr.Substring(6, 13));
DateTime date = new DateTime(ticks);
```

There will be a difference between .Net and javascript tick value:

> The JavaScript Date type's origin is the Unix epoch: midnight on 1 January 1970. The .NET DateTime type's origin is midnight on 1 January 0001. If by "ticks" you mean something like "milliseconds since the epoch", you can call ".getTime()
>
> There are 621355968000000000 epoch ticks for javascript from Ist Jan 1900 to Ist Jan 1970. And here 10000 are the ticks per milliseconds.

quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966559/how-to-convert-javascript-date-object-to-ticks). You will need to correct for this. the last line would look like the following:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(ticks * 10000 + 621355968000000000);
```

Comment: Using this code I get a date ( {02/01/0001 17:05:25} ) but the original date was "Wed Nov 16 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100". Could it be a problem with the date format? I need to use dd/mm/yyyy. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the string "/Date(1479250800000)/" as a date value in javascript if you are sending it from C#. But if you sending back the value to a date field in C# then the value will be deserialized as DateTime value. You don't need to convert it explicitly, just get it in a DateTime field.

Comment: You're right but I need to deserialize it as String because this field can contain any type of data. I just need to convert that string in a valid DateTime. Big thanks.